# Is it meaningful to ask whether first-order logic is consistent?

Tags: definition, first-order-logic

Is it meaningful to ask whether first-order logic, as opposed to a particular theory with axioms stated using first order logic, is consistent?

---

If we assume first-order logic as our framework, then we can ask whether particular theories are consistent.

We can define a first-order theory as a set of sentences $\mathrm{T}$. In the standard syntax for first-order logic it is possible to infer, for any given symbol, whether it is a function or a predicate symbol and its arity. We can handle constant symbols by treating them as nullary functions (e.g. $c()$). Thus we can infer a signature for any theory from its sentences alone. And we can treat sentences completely syntactically as sequences of symbols.

For a given theory, we can ask whether it is consistent or not. Questions like *is ZFC consistent* or *is Peano arithmetic consistent* are certainly meaningful.

I'm wondering whether it makes sense to ask whether first-order logic *itself* is consistent or not.

- Does it make sense to ask whether FOL is consistent?
- Is FOL known to be consistent?
- Is asking about the consistency of FOL *the same*, in some sense, as asking whether the empty theory $\mathrm{T} = \{\}$ is consistent?

Comment: Re: 1 and 3, I don't know what "FOL is consistent" could possibly mean *except* that $\emptyset$ is consistent as an FOL-theory. Re: 2, just argue that (for example) the theory of a one-element structure (in a given language) is deductively closed and doesn't contain $\perp$.

Comment: Good point. a) I wanted to leave the door open to talk about classical FOL among things-that-resemble-predicate-logic in a general way where it might make sense to distinguish the "consistency of the logic itself" from its theories including $\varnothing$. I don't know why you'd need or want to do this, but I wanted to leave the door open. b) I'm worried that defining the consistency of FOL as the consistency of $\varnothing$ within FOL might be circular in a way that I can't immediately see.

Comment: Yes it is. You have to recall that the first modern development of mathematical logic treated it as a "theory" based on logical axioms and rules. Thus, since the beginning (Frege, Hilbert) the question arise how to prove that the chosen axioms and rules do not produced unexpected results. The answer was quite simple, as a by-product of "soundness".

Comment: See e.g. the first modern ML textbook: [Hilbert & Ackermann (1928)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Principles_of_Mathematical_Logic/45ZGMjV9vfcC), **Ch.12 The Consistency of the System of Axioms** (English transl. page 38 for prop calculus and page 87 for FOL).